# Питон не видит символы мастей карт

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
answer = "6♥️A♥️J♥️ 8♦️J♣️9♠️"
for i in answer:
    if i == "♥️":
        print("черви")
    else:
       continue
```

Comment: Что значит "не видит"?

Comment: не выводит print("черви") и пропускает его

Comment: поменяйте символ в if на символ из строки. они у вас не совподают.

Comment: А вообще не питонист, но почему в ответах нет простого `u"..."`?

Answer (score 3):

Этот символ на самом деле состоит из двух символов, а строка итерируется по одному символу, из-за этого сравнение не срабатывает. Но можно проверить, например так, взяв только первый символ от изображения сердечка:

```
answer = "6♥️A♥️J♥️ 8♦️J♣️9♠️"
for i in answer:
    if i == "♥️"[0]:
        print("черви")
    else:
       continue
```

Результат:

```
черви
черви
черви
```

Проверка, что там внутри, какие символы:

```
print(list(map(hex,map(ord,"♥️"))))
print(list(map(hex,map(ord, "6♥️A♥️J♥️ 8♦️J♣️9♠️"))))
```

Результат:

```
['0x2665', '0xfe0f']
['0x36', '0x2665', '0xfe0f', '0x41', '0x2665', '0xfe0f', '0x4a', '0x2665', '0xfe0f', '0x20', '0x38', '0x2666', '0xfe0f', '0x4a', '0x2663', '0xfe0f', '0x39', '0x2660', '0xfe0f']
```

[Невидимый элемент кода, который указывает, что предыдущий символ должен отображаться в виде Эмоджи](https://unicode-table.com/ru/FE0F/)

Comment: спасибо огромное! не ожидал, что мне кто нибудь поможет с таким вопросом)

Comment: @verbtobe А вообще на будущее самый надёжный метод - печатать как можно больше на экран в программе и переменные и ход выполнения, иногда вот посимвольно. И всё становится понятно )

Comment: как понимать "печатать как можно больше на экран в программе и переменные и ход выполнения"?

Comment: @verbtobe ну ставите print() с интересующими переменными в разных местах программы, чтобы видеть, что происходит

Answer (score 3):

Потому что из строки вы получаете по одному символу, а при сравнении там где у вас сердечко в условии на самом деле два символа:

```
answer = "♥️"  # скопировано из вашего условия
for i in answer:
    print(repr(i), hex(ord(i)))
```

Выведет:

```
'♥' 0x2665
'️' 0xfe0f
```

Невидимый символ с кодом 0xfe0f - [селектор начертания](https://unicode-table.com/ru/FE0F/).

Чтобы не ошибиться, и не скопировать случайно в условие лишние символы, можно сравнивать напрямую с символом с кодом 0x2665:

```
answer = "6♥️A♥️J♥️ 8♦️J♣️9♠️"
for i in answer:
    if i == "\u2665":  # Или так: ord(i) == 0x2665
        print("черви")
```

Вывод:

```
черви
черви
черви
```

Comment: а что означает \u в вашем выражении?

Comment: @verbtobe, это обозначение юникодного символа в строке через его код. По сути получится то же самое сердечко, если его вывести через `print("\u2665")`

Comment: мой способ проверки проще ))

Comment: @CrazyElf, мой надежнее. Если текст откуда-то скопирован, то в нем может оказаться еще куча невидимых символов типа пробела нулевой ширины, и неизвестно в итоге какой индекс будет у самого сердечка.

Comment: Да тут без разницы) По сути ваши ответы оба правильные

Comment: Как посмотреть 16-ричные коды символов опять же можно посмотреть у меня в ответе. К такому коду можно приписать \u вместо 0x и получится обратно символ по коду.

Comment: @CrazyElf, да спасибо. Сразу это заметил)